# Pasar una consulta obtenida en formato Json a una vista en asp.net core mvc

Tags: json, linq, asp.net-core

Buen día a todos los compañeros del foro

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero obtener el siguiente resultado en una vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puede observarse, la consulta tiene que extraer la fecha mas reciente de cada grupo

actualmente la realizo con el siguiente código de consulta:

```
var query = from p in _context.Reporting
                        
                        group p by p.VesselId into op
                        select new
                        {
                            VesselID = op.Key,
                            EntryTime = op.Max(x => x.EntryTime)
                        };

            return Json(await query.ToListAsync());
```

y lo que obtengo es el resultado de la consulta en formato Json siguiente:

```
[{"vesselID":26,"entryTime":"2020-07-18T15:35:00"},{"vesselID":27,"entryTime":"2020-07-14T09:33:00"}]
```

Mi pregunta es... ¿como paso ese Json a una vista? o de que otra forma mas fácil puedo hacer esa consulta y pasarla a la vista, que puedo hacer para pasar ese Json a un  o a un  en la vista.

Les agradeceré toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

saludos y muchísimas gracias

Comment: Veo que estas retornando el JSON por lo menos... tu problema es que no llega al front? o que lo quieres en otro formato?

Comment: Gracias por contestar Paulo, lo que necesito es que lo mande al front (Vista) en un <table> o una <ul>, es decir no lo quiero en formato JSON, quiero pasarlo a un control html en la vista.

Comment: Pero eso es JQuery, recibes los datos como JSON y en el front vas recorriendo la data y adaptandola a tus necesidades con JQuery, React, Angular, etc :)

Comment: Muchas Gracias Paulo, Algún ejemplo con el que me puedas apoyar?